# SAS-Dynamically Writing Bar Charts to Excel workbook in SAS Macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro, sas-ods

I am trying to dynamically generate and export bar charts to and an excel workbook.  My Macro pulls certain distinct Identifier codes and creates two summary tables (prov_&x table and the prov_revcd_&x) and populates to single excel sheet, for each respective ID.  I have been unable however to successfully generate bar charts for the data and export to excel.  Below is a condensed version of code.  I have removed the steps for creating the prov_&x table and the prov_revcd_&x table to help keep the post as concise as possible.  I have tried using the GOUT function and NAME function and then explicitly calling those but that does not seem to work.  Any suggestions are welcomed and I understand my macro code is a little sloppy but it generates the tables so I will clean up once I can get the bar charts to generate.

Also, I can see in my results viewer that the graphs are generating, so I'm assuming the problem is in how I am trying to reference them to the workbook. THANKS!

```
%macro runtab(x);

/*Create summary chart for generating graph of codes billed per month*/
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE summary_&x AS
select DISTINCT month, COUNT (CH_ICN) AS ICN_Count, CLI_Revenue_Cd_Category_Cd
FROM corf_data1_sorted
WHERE BP_Billing_Prov_Num_OSCAR=&x
group by month ,CLI_Revenue_Cd_Category_Cd;
run;

/*Create a graph of Services Per Month and group by the Revenue Code*/
proc sgplot data=summary_&x NAME= 'graph_&x';
  title 'Provider Revenue Analysis';
  vbar month / response=ICN_count group=CLI_Revenue_Cd_Category_Cd stat=sum
       datalabel datalabelattrs=(weight=bold);
  yaxis grid  label='Month';
  run;
%mend runtab;


/*Create a macro variable of all the codes */
proc sql noprint;
  select BP_Billing_Prov_Num_OSCAR
  into :varlist separated by ' ' /*Each code in the list is sep. by a single space*/
from provider;
quit;


%let cntlist = &sqlobs; /*Store a count of the number of oscar codes*/
%put &varlist; /*Print the codes to the log to be sure our list is accurate*/



/*write a macro to generate the output tables*/
%macro output(x);


ods tagsets.excelxp options(sheet_interval='none' sheet_name="&x");

proc print data=prov_&x;
run;

proc print data=prov_revcd_&x;
run;

proc print data=graph_&x;
run;  

%mend;

/*Run a loop for each oscar code. Each code will enter the document generation loop*/
%macro loopit(mylist);
    %let else=;
   %let n = %sysfunc(countw(&mylist)); /*let n=number of codes in the list*/
    data
   %do I=0 %to &n;
      %let val = %scan(&mylist,&I); /*Let val= the ith code in the list*/
    %end;


   %do j=0 %to &n;
      %let val = %scan(&mylist,&j); /*Let val= the jth code in the list*/
/*Run the macro loop to generate the required tables*/
%runtab(&val);


%output(&val);


   %end;
   run;
%mend;


/*Run the macro loop over the list of significant procedure code values*/


ods tagsets.excelxp file="W:\user\test_wkbk.xml";


%loopit(&varlist)


ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't export charts with `ODS TAGSETS.EXCELXP`, unfortunately.

You have a few options if you need to export charts.

1. Use ODS Excel, available in the more recent maintenance releases of SAS 9.4.  See [Chris H's blog post](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2014/08/29/experimenting-with-ods-excel-to-create-spreadsheets-from-sas/) for more information on that.  It is fairly similar to Tagsets.ExcelXP, but not identical.  It does generate a "Real" excel file (.xlsx).
2. Create an HTML file that Excel can read, using TAGSETS.MSOFFICE2K or regular HTML.  Chevell Parker, a SAS tech support analyst, has a few papers like [this one](http://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2010/excel_db/MWSUG-2010-113.pdf) on the different options.
3. Use DDE to write your image to the excel file.  Not a preferred option but included for completeness.

There is also a new proc - `proc mschart` - that is enabled in SAS 9.4 TS1M3 due out in a month or two, that will generate Excel charts in `ODS EXCEL` (ie, not an image, but telling Excel to make a chart here please).